# ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I want to create trigger but i get this error.ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS
04089. 00000 -  "cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS"

How can i solve this problem?.Why cannot I create triggers on objects owned by SYS?

```
create table superhero(name varchar2(30));

create or replace trigger tg_sup
before insert on superhero
for each row disable
declare
v_user varchar2(30);
begin
select user into v_user from dual;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line('you just inserted a line by '||v_user);
end;
```

Comment: [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html#GUID-CF1CD853-AF15-41EC-BC80-61918C73FDB5): "You must not create any tables in the SYS schema." As Littlefoot said, create your own user, and create objects under that schema instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told: you can't do it in `SYS` schema. It, just like `SYSTEM`, is *special*, it owns the database and should only be used for maintenance purposes. Create your own user to brush SQL skills; for example, I have the `scott` user:

```
SQL> create table superhero
  2    (name varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger tg_sup
  2    before insert on superhero
  3    for each row
  4  disable
  5  declare
  6    v_user varchar2(30);
  7  begin
  8    select user into v_user from dual;
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line('you just inserted a line by '||v_user);
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> insert into superhero(name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.
```

Good; but, there's no message (from the trigger). How come? Because you chose to create it in `disabled` state (why did you do that?):

```
SQL> select status from user_Triggers where trigger_name = 'TG_SUP';

STATUS
--------
DISABLED
```

If we enable it:

```
SQL> alter trigger tg_sup enable;

Trigger altered.

SQL> insert into superhero(name) values ('Bigfoot');
you just inserted a line by SCOTT                        --> message!

1 row created.

SQL>
```

OK, message is being displayed.